# Trim transparency of an UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage

I was wondering what would be the best way to trim the "canvas" of an UIImage (pretty much like any image editor allows out there)

[image: Example]

Now, the previous example is not a single UIImage. It's actually 2 UIViews. So clipping the superview against the blue box would do the trick, but I guess I am looking into the best possible way to do this. Given that there could be several blue boxes in the "canvas".

Is there a faster way than going through every pixel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was being dumb. The union of the subviews is all I really needed, so its just a simple loop over the subviews and doing a CGRect union against their frames.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it algorithmically, I would say no. You need to find the pixel that extends furthest to the left, right, top and bottom. Unless you look at every pixel from each direction you could miss non-transparent pixels.

You could speed things up if you figure out how to map your image into memory and then index into memory directly rather than using a high level function that fetches pixels. I would suggest searching from the top down (which would be sequential memory accesses) until you find a non-clear pixel. Then search from the end of the image backwards, which would give you the bottom-most pixel.

You would then want to limit your search from each side to only look starting at the first non-transparent pixel from the top and ending at the last non-transparent pixel on the bottom.

For anything other than a very large image this should take a fraction of a second.

Comment: Thanks for the info Duncan, I have updated the question to reflect the real problem. Given that it may be way simpler this way